# C# How can i get the available code page identifiers?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way of getting all the available  [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) on the current system in C# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var codepages = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(x => x.GetEncoding()).ToList();
```

You can get any info you need from this encodings like

```
var names = codepages.Select(x => x.BodyName).ToList();
var ids = codepages.Select(x => x.CodePage).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that info from Encodings, use the following code to get codes and names:

```
var codepages = Encoding.GetEncodings().ToList();
```

[image: codepages]

Answer (score -1):

You want to get the `EncodingInfo`, which is what @Eser is pointing out. Specifically, to get the code pages that you're looking for, you could look at the `CodePage` property of the `EncodingInfo` returned.

```
var codepages = 
    Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(e => new {e.DisplayName, e.Name, e.CodePage})
       .ToList().Dump();
```

This returns you (LINQPad results):

[image: Using LINQPad]

Comment: What does this answer say other than @eser says  (especially, when posted 10 mins later)?

Comment: @I4V: look a bit closer at my code, friend.

Comment: I did. and the keyword here is `Encoding.GetEncodings()` which is already posted..

Comment: `Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(x => x.GetEncoding()).` - different call, bud. And nested.